# Why doesn't Gran Turismo save on PSX for Mac?

Tags: macos, emulation, gran-turismo, pcsx

I'm playing Gran Turismo on my iBook g4, it works really well. I save my games all the time to both the digital memory cards when I'm quitting. However when I try to load a game  it says "No Save Files found" in each memory cards.

Why does this happen, is it possible to fix?

Computer: iBook g4 PowerPc g4 1.42 GHz

Answer (score -1):

Really i never played gran turismo on the ibook but i think is about the ibook incapability to save on the memory card.Try save it on something else or switch the memory card(it might be him the cause just try another one)